# Intent within fragment works only half the time

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

I am trying to pass an intent with data from Activity A to FragmentActivity B to Fragment B. A button from Activity A starts FragmentActivity B. The "year" string sets a filter with which I query a mysql database on a remote server. The code below works but only half the time.

I have no idea what causes it to filter just some times and at other times it just returns the whole table unfiltered. I am guessing it has to be related to the intent I am using in the fragment because the filter worked without issue in the version of the app without the fragment. It also seems inefficient the way I am sending the intent from Activity A to FragmentActivity B to Fragment B. How can I fix this problem?

Activity A:

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(FindMovie.this, ShowMovies.class);

            intent.putExtra("year", year1);

            startActivity(intent);
   }
    });
```

FragmentActivity B:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_movies);
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG) == null) {
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, new ImageGridFragment(), TAG);
        ft.commit();
    }



    Intent i = getIntent();

    year = i.getStringExtra("year");

              //resend through another intent to the fragment B
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageGridFragment.class);


        intent.putExtra("year", year);
   }
```

Fragment B:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_grid_fragment, container, false);


    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();

    year = extras.getString("year");

 return v;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a thread timing issue, your FragmentActivityB is creating the fragment, which is sent to a thread (I would think) and then you are adding the new value from the original thread, and sometimes the second thread is fast enough to execute FragmentB `onCreateView` before it gets the new value. What you can do is add the value of `'year'` during the FragmentTransaction.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Create a new fragment and bundle
    Fragment fragment = new ImageGridFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    // Put variables in bundle and add to fragment
    bundle.putString("year", getIntent().getStringExtra("year"));
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    // Insert the fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

In FragmentB get the `'year'` like this:

`year = getArguments().getString("year");`

I think this would solve the issue, let me know what happens though,

Cheers.

Comment: What a fantastic answer! Thank you so much. It solved the issue. "thread timing issue" was the problem, I actually only had to move the async task below the Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
  
  year = extras.getString("year");

Comment: LuckyMe, this really worked. I have a small issue, my fragment is in a sweapable tab view and required fragment is in 5th tab. when i use this code, it straightaway loding the 5th screen. how can i change it