# Avoid loading the 5th tab in 1st attempt in my android swipeable tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have a fragment in a sweapable tab view and i want to show my email address in the required fragment(it is in 5th tab). when i use this code, it straightaway loading the 5th screen. how can i change it.
I want to load the 1st tab first as a normal tab.

I used the answer in this, [Intent within fragment works only half the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226251/intent-within-fragment-works-only-half-the-time)

public class ActivityMenu extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
-----tag-----------------------------------------------------   
    Fragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    // Put variables in bundle and add to fragment
    bundle.putString("user", getIntent().getStringExtra("user"));
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    // Insert the fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment)
            .commit();
---------------------------------------------------------------------

//      String email = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_p));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_n));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_s));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_p));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_tab_p));
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    // set background for action bar tab
    bar.show();

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

adapter

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new PFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new PiFragment();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new SFragment();
        case 3:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new PFragment();
        case 4:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new PrFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 5;
    }

}
```

i think im getting this because im creating new bundle, but how can i overcome it, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: show your adapter class

Comment: can u check my updated question, i hav shown some code inside 2 doted lines. if i removed that piece of code then the tab perfectly works

Comment: why did you put those codes inside dot line? they should be in adapter

Comment: i wanted to show the logged in email address in when user logged in. so i followed the tutorial i have mentioned in the question (did u see the link i have mentioned in the question).

Comment: with that piece of code, i can load the email address. but the issue is it by default it loads the 5th tab, i

Comment: so move those codes (without `insert ...`) into 5th tab in `getItem()` of adapter

Comment: i put this part to adapter, Fragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

      
      bundle.putString("email", getIntent().getStringExtra("email"));
      fragment.setArguments(bundle);------- then it gives an error to getIntent(). The method getIntent() is undefined for the type TabsPagerAdapter

Comment: Ok I write answer for you now

Comment: it will be great if u could do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In activity, in `onCreate()` get emailStr, and remove all other dotted lines, instance adapter with a extra parameter `emailStr`:

```
String emailStr = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");

mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), emailStr);
```

In adapter, change constructor accordingly, and set argument for 5th tab fragment:

```
private String user = null;

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String user) {
    super(fm);

    this.user = user;
}

... ...

//add those codes to 5th tab fragment
Fragment fragment = new ProfileFragment(); 
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putString("email", user); 
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
return fragment;
```

Hope this will be working!